# Django: passing context instance as context to render function

Tags: django, templates, request, render

Can I use

```
render_to_string('some_path', RequestContext(request, {'foo': 'bar'}))
```

instead of

```
render_to_string('some_path', {'foo': 'bar'}, RequestContext(request))
```

?

Comment: I believe `render_to_string('some_path', context_instance = RequestContext(request, {'foo': 'bar'}))` should work. 
`

Comment: @karthikr: that will surely work cause the first line of the function is dictionary = dictionary or {}. But that is different from the two options in the question. The second option I present is directly from docs. The first is not but it works for me and I use it in one of my template tags where I have got access to context instance. The question is if I can get into any trouble out of the fact that context instance does not implement the whole dictionary interface. I guess not but also it would be probably better to stick to what is in docs and possibly use the option you suggest.

Comment: @karthikr: Nevertheless I would be glad if someone would say that I can use the first option without any worries. It feels more natural to me and I think it should be possible.

Comment: Now, in your usecase, the second argument would be a positional argument, and would be assigned to the second parameter in the called method, which is `dictionary` in this case. So, the short answer - No

Comment: @karthikr: that is the point of this question.